# amplitude at exact frequency in wide band signal

Tags: filters, fourier-transform, amplitude, bode

Could anyone suggest the most computationaly efficient method for finding amplitude of exact frequency having a noisy wide band signal.

To be more specific about a task. I have some physical dynamical system. I'm introducing sinusoidal input with exact frequency and amplitude. And looking for the amplitude at the same frequency on the output signal. While output signal is subject to noise and affected by other physical inputs at the same time.

This is required to detect some aspects of physical model. Experiments shows that this kind of test is sensitive to physical changes I want to detect.

Also I quite limited in recources. I only have small 32 bit MCU that is capable only of fixed point arithmetics. Or very slow emulated floating point. Thats why I'm asking about most effective solutions to the task.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just implemented with bandpass IIR and checking amplitude. Now looking at [Goertzel_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm) to achieve more presize calculation.

Comment: Now trying to make Goertzel algorithm work 'online'. I mean is it possible to make that algorithm detect amplitude changing with time. To work like real filter and not in batch mode. The way it is implemented it requires N calculations to give an answer and than again one should use N calculations. Any suggestions?

Comment: Moved over sliding Goertzel algorithm to sliding DFT (SDFT). It is capable of producing DFT every sample. And extremely computationaly efficient at each step.